# Controller displaying json data instead of html

Tags: php, json, ajax, laravel, controller

I am trying to fetch data using data and it is returning json in whole page.

This is my code on Controller to fetch products:

```
public function products(){
   $allProducts = $this->product->has('Sizes')->has('Images')->paginate(9);

    $prodCategories = $this->products_categories->get();
    return response()->json( $allProducts);

}
```

And in the ajax, I have the following code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('displayProduct') }}",
            dataType: 'json',
            method: 'get',
            data: { _token:"{{ csrf_token() }}"},
            success(response){
                let array = response.data;
                if(array == 0){
                    html += '<div class="block"><h2 class="aside-title">Product not found!</h2><p class="errorProduct">Sorry! There is no product in this category. Please search products on other categories</p></div>';
                    $('#productClick').html(html);
                }

                $.each( array, function( key, value ) {
                    let image = jQuery.makeArray(value.images);
                    html += '<div class="product-layout product-layout-table col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-12">';
                    html += '<div class="product-box clearfix">';
                    html += '<div class="product-image">';
                    html += '<a href="/product/'+value.slug+'" class="c-img link-product">';
                    html += '<img src="'+image[0]['image']+'" class="img-responsive" alt=""></a>';
                    html += '<a class="smooth quickview iframe-link btn-button quickview quickview_handler visible-lg" href="/quick/'+value.slug+'" title="Quick view" target="_self" data-fancybox-type="iframe">';
                    html += '<i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>';
                    html += '<div class="product-info"><h4 class="product-name"><a href="/product/'+value.slug+'" class="smooth" title="">'+value.title+'</a></h4>';
                    html += '<div class="price">'+value.price+' <span class="price-old">$142.00</span></div>';
                    html += '<div class="product-desc">';
                    html += '<p>'+value.excerpt+'</p></div></div>';
                    html += '<div class="button-group"><button class="add-to-cart smooth" onclick="window.location.href=\'cart.html\'">ADD TO CART</button></div></div></div></div></div>';
                });
                $('#productClick').html(html);
                loadIframe();
            }
        });
    });
```

But, when I load the product I am getting json data on the whole page.

The function loadFrame has following code:

```
function loadIframe(){
        $.getScript( "ajax/test.js" )
    }
```

Comment: What does that loadIframe() function do?

Comment: @AhmedShefeer loadframe() to reload the js file.

Comment: Why would you want to reload a js file? Can you please elaborate the question more? I dont see anything that reloads the page in your code, are you sure the page isn't reloaded from the loadIframe() function? Can you post the code for that function?

Comment: @AhmedShefeer That function has nothing to do with the json data that I am receiving on the page load. Please check the question, I have edited it,

Comment: Is the html logged correctly if you use a console.log(html); and return; before the $('#productClick').html(html); line is called?

Comment: @AhmedShefeer I have removed all the ajax code from the `<script></script>` of product page. I think the problem is on controller.